# Add # (pound) sign at begining of the line matching.(search string : file path)

Tags: sed, awk, vi

file:

```
sh  xyz/abc/www/def/gef/rqs/
sh xyz/toh/aaa/def/gef/rqs/
sh xyz/123/qqq/def/gef/rqs/
```

I want changes like this

```
sh  xyz/abc/www/def/gef/rqs/
#sh xyz/toh/aaa/def/gef/rqs/
sh xyz/123/qqq/def/gef/rqs/
```

edited: file paths to match my problem statement.

Comment: Based on what criteria, exactly?

Comment: The line with xyz/toh/aaa should be commented

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
sed -i '\%xyz/toh/aaa% s/^/#/' file
```

Explanation:

- `\%` set the regex delimiter to `%` (so as not to conflict with the path separator `/`)
- match `xyz/toh/aaa`
- replace the start of line `^` by `#

Comment: Thanks you made my day, also i want to add, sed -i '\%'$file_path/$var'% s/^/#/' file if you need to use variables in it.

Answer (score 0):

And why not using `vim`?

```
vi -c 'g/xyz\/toh\/aaa/s/^/#/ | x' file
```

or

```
vi -c '%s!.* xyz/toh/aaa!#&! | x' file
```